# Executing a Spring Batch job incrementer when running through JUnit

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job which takes parameters, and the parameters are usually the same every time the job is run.  By default, Spring Batch doesn't let you re-use the same parameters like that... so I created a simple incrementer and added it to my job like this:

http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/multiple-batch-runs-with-spring-batch/

When using the standard `CommandLineJobRunner` to run my job, I have to pass the `-next` parameter in order for my incrementer to be used.

However, when I run an end-to-end job test from within a JUnit class, using `JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob( JobParameters )`... I can't find a way to declare that my incrementer should be used.  The job is just quietly skipped, presumably because it has already been run with those parameters (see note below).

The `JobParameters` class is meant to hold a collection of name-value pairs... but the -next parameter is different.  It starts with a dash, and has no corresponding value.  I tried various experiments, but trying to add something to the `JobParameters` collection doesn't seem to be the ticket.

Does anyone know the JUnit equivalent to passing `-next` to `CommandLineJobRunner`?

NOTE:  I presume that the the issue is my incrementer being ignored, because:

1. The job works the first time, and it works if I wipe out the job repository database.  It only fails on retries.
2. The job works fine, retries and all, when I hardcode the variables and remove the parameters altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobLauncherTestUtils class contains a getUniqueJobParameters method which serves exactly the same need.

```
/**
* @return a new JobParameters object containing only a parameter for the
* current timestamp, to ensure that the job instance will be unique.
*/
public JobParameters getUniqueJobParameters() {Map<String, JobParameter> 
parameters = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
parameters.put("random", new JobParameter((long) (Math.random() * JOB_PARAMETER_MAXIMUM)));
return new JobParameters(parameters);
}
```

Sample usage would be,

```
JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder (jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters()).toJobParameters();
     //extra parameters to be added
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(params);
```

Comment: Huh... so the unit test doesn't really test a job's iterator, but rather bypasses the need for it altogether.  A lot of things about Spring Batch have been non-intuitive for me so far... but this approach did solve my problem, so thanks!